# How to represent an HMM whose observations are a continuous vector?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have usually read about HMMs with observation spaces that we can somehow encode as a finite number of observations. How could I use HMM fitting if my observation at each time step is an $n$-dimensional continuous vector instead of a discrete symbol?

Comment: it would be exactly the same except that your observation likelihood would take the form of some continuous distribution (e.g normal). Is this what you were after? What exactly would u like to know?

Comment: I guess my question is how to do HMM when the emission matrix doesn't exist (like in this seting).

Comment: The emission matrix still exists. Instead of having output probabilities, you have a function mapping from the value of the latent states to the mean (and potentially covariance) of a Gaussian distribution.